# Table Sorting with muticolumn header and body values using table sorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

My table header contains two row headers and i cannot able to sort the column after column containing colspan. My table structure as described in [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rajeswarik/RwFUt/). I need to sort the last column in my table structure based on both headers Amount and Date/time. But i have no idea why it is not sorting. Any idea or suggestions might be helpful.

Comment: perhaps because your table does not follow the usual stucture, you have the data every alternate column

Comment: same problem here also http://jsfiddle.net/prabud/wB8bk/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark W. but this table structure is the requirement.

Comment: Must change the HTML structure to use single rows.  You can have nexted blocks inside those rows to simulate your current structure, and write parses that grab values from inside.

Comment: Thanks Joe Coder. But i need to use my own method to get values from nested blocks or i can use table sorter plugin itself? Any idea or links will be useful for me

Comment: One thing you could try is to clone the table, remove id, colspan and all in the cloned table. Make the cloned table a simple one that tablesorter can sort. Then, on clicking of the original table's row header, trigger a sort for the cloned table and copy back just the cell values from the cloned table to original table

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the sourcecode for tablesorter,

jquery.tablesorter.js">http://tablesorter.com/_jquery.tablesorter.js, particularly the function

function computeTableHeaderCellIndexes(t) for example..

Its trying to map columns to headers which will never work in your case - its just not designed to do what you're trying to get it to do...

You do have a slight bug in your structure, the second  tr is missing a colspan="2"